# I don't understand something about use taking dft with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, dft

I am new in using `opencv` library. These days I am trying to use `dft()` but  there is something  that I don't understand before use `dft()` and after use `dft()`. Can you help me understand that ?

I looked some youtube videos about that but again I don't understand too.

```
 Mat padded;                          
int m = getOptimalDFTSize( I.rows );
int n = getOptimalDFTSize( I.cols );
copyMakeBorder(I, padded, 0, m - I.rows, 0, n - I.cols, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0)); //here we are expanding the photo but i dont understand the operation in here



 Mat q0(magI, Rect(0, 0, cx, cy));   
    Mat q1(magI, Rect(cx, 0, cx, cy));  
    Mat q2(magI, Rect(0, cy, cx, cy));  
    Mat q3(magI, Rect(cx, cy, cx, cy)); 

    Mat tmp;                           
    q0.copyTo(tmp);
    q3.copyTo(q0);  //here we are rearring the quadrants but how
    tmp.copyTo(q3);

    q1.copyTo(tmp);                    
    q2.copyTo(q1);
    tmp.copyTo(q2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copyMakeBorder` is being used to make the image the right size for an optimal dft calculation.  The dft can be performed more quickly if it is performed on an optimal sized image, documentation is available [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga6577a2e59968936ae02eb2edde5de299)

The quadrants are rearranged as part of an `fftshift` operation, [`matlab`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html) and [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftshift.html)  both have functions that do this.  The purpose is just to help with visual analysis, `fftshift` moves low frequencies to the center of the image and more clearly reveals symmetry in the magnitude of the dft.